# Links not clickable in Rich Document Text View in macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I am creating a tiny app for macOS using Swift and I have a `Rich Document Text View` in my view controller. In this Text View, I have a link to a website that is formatted correctly, i.e color is blue and is underlined. However, when I click on it, nothing happens. Even the cursor doesn't change when I hover on the link.

Any ideas on how to make it clickable?

If it can't be done this way then I can create a label and make it open a website programmatically like below:

```
@objc private func linkClicked() {
    guard let url: URL = URL(string: "https://blog.rampatra.com") else { return }
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
}
```

but was thinking if it could be done in the `Text View` itself by setting some properties in Xcode then nothing like it. Speaking of properties in Xcode, I tried enabling the `Smart Links` flag on Xcode for this View but no luck.

Comment: Is the text view [`selectable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449297-isselectable)?

Comment: That's great. Making it `selectable` on Xcode worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in text views aren't interactive unless the text view is "selectable". So, you have to enable that. If you don't really want to allow for selection, as [documented for the `isSelectable` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449297-isselectable), you can implement `textView(_:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:)` in the text view delegate to disallow actual selection.

Answer (score -1):

NSTextView has `isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled`
Did you try that?

Comment: Is `isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled` the Smart Links flag? This answer should be a comment.

Comment: I guess this flag isn't available on Xcode. I am more inclined towards some setting on Xcode itself and not achieving the results programmatically.